# -[UIView setRegion:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, mapkit, core-location

I am a beginner in Objective C. I am setting a Mapview after selecting a TableRow inside a Navigation controller. I am getting this error which terminates the application.

```
-[UIView setRegion:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x806b2c0
```

This is my viewWillAppeer for Mapview

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
    zoomLocation.latitude = 39.281516;
    zoomLocation.longitude= -76.580806;

    if (CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(location)) {
        MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE);

        [_mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated:YES];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Invalid coordinates");
    }
}
```

Header file for this imports mapkit and corelocation and has this property.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
```

Header file includes mapkit and coreelocation and making this property strong also didn't changed anything.

Comment: your _mapView object is corrupted at the time of method call.

Comment: can u ensure that IBoutlet is connected?

Comment: I think I forgot to do an alloc on mapView

Comment: what?? "forgot to alloc"? - it is an IBoutlet. You are explicitly allocating it? - it should have been linked to the Mapview of XIB.

Comment: Oops!! It just suppressed the error so I though that might be the problem.  I have a storyboard and gutter shows I have my IBOutlet connected. Still getting same error

Comment: Can you check mapView.m file target is selected or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened because I previously hooked an outlet on my LocateItemViewController (the controller having map view) named "mapView" and never deleted it from "Connections Inspector".

[image: see the greyed outlet named "view" under Outlets section, I had a similar one named mapView]

see the greyed outlet named "view" under Outlets section, I had a similar one named mapView

Answer (score 0):

the variable `_mapView` is modified to an `UIView`. The function belongs to `MKMapView` instead of `UIView`.

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html

Comment: I function call to `[self.mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated:YES];` and property to `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;`

Comment: try to `NSLog(@"%@", _mapView);` in the question's code. I wonder what value does it set to.

Comment: screenshot of console with `NSLog(@"%@",self.mapView);`: http://snag.gy/fC1wd.jpg

Comment: it's really a `UIView`! you'd better find & replace `_mapView` and see what you have assigned to it.

Comment: The controller is definitely a subclass of UIView but my property definition clearly states that its a MKMapView. I have no custom setter.